# EventsAdapter() in EventsAdapater cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

i try to make custom listview, then I get errors, and i don't know why.

there was an error at `this, R.layout.list_events_item,listEvents`

and the error message is:

[image]

EventsFragment.java

```java
public class EventsFragment extends Fragment {
    private View paramView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events,container,false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.listViewEvents);
        List<Events> listEvents = new ArrayList<Events>();
        Events events = new Events(1,"12:00","A1221",
                "Error at the same place","1.2.3.4","1.2.4.3","A212","123",443,1234);
        listEvents.add(events);
        events = new Events(2,"11:20","A1221",
                "Error at the same place","1.2.3.4","1.2.4.3","A212","123",443,1234);
        listEvents.add(events);
        listView.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(this, R.layout.list_events_item,listEvents));

        return paramView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

EventsAdapter.java

```java
public class EventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Events> {
    List<Events> listEvents;
    Context context;
    int layout;
    public EventsAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Events> listEvents){
        super(context,layout,listEvents);
        this.context=context;
        this.layout=layout;
        this.listEvents=listEvents;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        EventsHolder holder;
        if (v == null){
            LayoutInflater vi=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            holder = new EventsHolder();
            holder.time=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.signature = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.signatureId);
            holder.sensor = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sensor);
            holder.attacker = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.attacker);
            holder.attacked = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.attacked);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder=(EventsHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        Events events = listEvents.get(position);
        holder.time.setText(events.getTime());
        holder.signature.setText(events.getSignature_id());
        holder.sensor.setText(events.getSensor());
        holder.attacker.setText(events.getAttacker_port());
        holder.attacked.setText(events.getAttacked_port());
        return v;
    }
    static class EventsHolder{
        TextView time;
        TextView signature;
        TextView sensor;
        TextView attacker;
        TextView attacked;
    }
}
```

my Events model

```java
public class Events {
    int id;
    String time;
    String signature_id;
    String alert_message;
    String ip_source;
    String ip_destination;
    String sensor;
    String protocol;
    int attacker_port;
    int attacked_port;

    public Events(int id, String time, String signature_id, String alert_message, String ip_source, String ip_destination, String sensor, String protocol, int attacker_port, int attacked_port) {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
        this.signature_id = signature_id;
        this.alert_message = alert_message;
        this.ip_source = ip_source;
        this.ip_destination = ip_destination;
        this.sensor = sensor;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.attacker_port = attacker_port;
        this.attacked_port = attacked_port;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getSignature_id() {
        return signature_id;
    }

    public void setSignature_id(String signature_id) {
        this.signature_id = signature_id;
    }

    public String getAlert_message() {
        return alert_message;
    }

    public void setAlert_message(String alert_message) {
        this.alert_message = alert_message;
    }

    public String getIp_source() {
        return ip_source;
    }

    public void setIp_source(String ip_source) {
        this.ip_source = ip_source;
    }

    public String getIp_destination() {
        return ip_destination;
    }

    public void setIp_destination(String ip_destination) {
        this.ip_destination = ip_destination;
    }

    public String getSensor() {
        return sensor;
    }

    public void setSensor(String sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }

    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public int getAttacker_port() {
        return attacker_port;
    }

    public void setAttacker_port(int attacker_port) {
        this.attacker_port = attacker_port;
    }

    public int getAttacked_port() {
        return attacked_port;
    }

    public void setAttacked_port(int attacked_port) {
        this.attacked_port = attacked_port;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `this` to `getActivity()`